# How to handle click to copy functionality in Selenium with Linux operating system

Tags: linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation

I have a scenario when i click on a copy button/icon some text will be copied form the application. The same text can be used to further actions. In windows when we click on the button/icon the text will be stored to clipboard, that can be extracted with below code, it  is working fine in Windows OS.

```
public static String getClipBoardText() {
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    Object string = "";
    try {
        string = clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return (String) string;
}
```

I am calling above method after `driver.findElement(By.xpath("copy button xpath")).click();`

When we executed the same script in pipeline(in our case Git Lab to Moon) the above method not returning the copied text. As Moon clusters is running in Linux operating system, clipboard not available in Linux.

Note: Moon is platform from kubernates similar to source lab or browser stack. It will create required browser session to execute the scripts.